# How to select text only in an anchor with image

Tags: html, css

Good day,

Im currently editing a link with image that was generated by a plugin that I am using, this is the structure it generates.

```
<a href="#"><img src="../../image.jpg">Text Here</a>
```

my question is how can I select the "Text Here" word so I can add property on it without affecting the image?

is there a way to achieve this without changing the structure?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: set styles for `<a>` tag `a{color:Red}`

Comment: so im guessing you cant change the structure? and what properties do you want to effect?

Comment: alert($("a").text());

Comment: do you want to set property to anchor tag ?

Comment: wrap text in span and apply to span tag, or use figure and apply to caption

Comment: yeah @jmore009 I cant change the structure.. I want like float, padding, background and margins if posible.. is there a way I could select it with just a simple css code?

Comment: Only elements can be made to float. You can't float a text node.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jtu89ou7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dh8xL3wk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you cant target just text inside of an `a` tag without some other identifier. But you can target an `img` tag. So I suggest just setting properties for both text and image, and overwite them using the `img` tag. So you could do something like:

```
a{
   font-size: 14px;
   color: red;
 }

a img{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

and so on.

Comment: I thought to suggest the same thing, but `float` will affect the container along with all its descendants. You can't float the text and then unfloat the image that came with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add styles for both `img` and `a`

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
a img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any">Text Here</a>
```

or something like this

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
a img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any">Text Here</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir @Vitorino Fernandes :) yeah I guess thats way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a span tag :

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="../../image.jpg">
   <span>Text Here</span>
</a>
```

then, style it like this :

```
a > span {
    // Give your text a style
}
```

Comment: my question is how can I select the text alone without changing its structure? is it possible? thanks for the answer :)

Comment: No problem sir @Michael Anthonio.. your willingness to help also counts alot :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can change the structure, even if you can't change the plugin that generates it:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var textNode = a.childNodes[1];
a.removeChild(textNode);
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = textNode.nodeValue;
a.appendChild(span);
```

```css
a span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Wikipedia-logo-ms.png/36px-Wikipedia-logo-ms.png">Text Here</a>
```

This will give you the ability to apply even such attributes as `float` to text alone, if you run this after the plugin. (Obviously, adapt the selector to your own structure, possibly using QSA and adding a loop.)

Comment: thanks for your answer sir @Amadan.. ur answer is also correct.. but I would like to use a simple css code for this one :)